# Debian 7 and chromium - java not working

Tags: linux, debian, java, chromium

Using debian 7, with chromium as my browser, I got jdk6-64 bit installed on my debian
But my chromium won't run java applets, it's saying it's missing on each website that try to run java.

How do I fix this?

thank you

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: No error, my chromium is just saying "missing plugin"

Comment: Do applets work in other browsers? Are you sure you have installed the java plugin and not just the jdk (development kit)?

Answer (score 0):

removing proprietary Java runtime and it's config files and installing its opensource substitution may help. Debian is known for it's unfriendly attitude to non-free packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge default-jre
sudo apt-get install openjdk
```

Comment: no package found 'openjdk'